# Collapse Function Not Working in Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to Bootstrap. I tried so many ways but when I click on the button, it shows the Quiz Answer but it can't collapse. I'm not sure what went wrong. Here's my code

```
                <a href="@("#QuizAns"+i)" id="quizAns" data-toggle="collapse" 
                      class="btn">Quiz Answer</a>
               <div id="@("QuizAns"+i)" class="collapse">
                    <span style=" border: 1px solid;">
                  Answer: @item.quizAns
                   </span>
               </div>
```

Comment: Also mention, which version of Bootstrap you are using.

Comment: @amarnath bootstrap 3

Answer (score 0):

# is required before your ID in `href`

```
 <a href="#YOUR_UNIQUE_ID" id="quizAns" data-toggle="collapse" class="btn">Quiz Answer</a>
 <div id="YOUR_UNIQUE_ID" class="collapse">
     <span style=" border: 1px solid;">
              Answer: @item.quizAns
     </span>
 </div>
```

Your code should look like this

```
 <a href="#@("#QuizAns"+i)" id="quizAns" data-toggle="collapse" class="btn">Quiz Answer</a>
 <div id="@("#QuizAns"+i)" class="collapse">
     <span style=" border: 1px solid;">
              Answer: @item.quizAns
     </span>
 </div>
```

Comment: What is the value you are getting here -> @("#QuizAns"+i)

Comment: the answer from the database

Comment: Have you tried `"#@('#QuizAns'+i)"` instead of `"#@("#QuizAns"+i)"`? Maybe the quotes break it.

Comment: Can you try manually enabling collapse. By doing this in your jquery $('.collapse').collapse()

Comment: @Tommy still can't. it stated an error : "too many characters in character literal".